# I don't understand how to async operations can make a HTTP server concurrent

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I am developing a HTTP server using boost asio. So far, I have been using async operations (`aync_read`, `async_write` etc.), but I want to make my server concurrent, that is, the same as a server that creates a new thread per each new client connected.

I have read some forums etc. and, apparently, a concurrent server can be made only by using the mentioned async operations. **I do not understand how is this possible.**

I mean, taking into account that the async operations' handlers are executed in the thread that called to `io_service.run()`, lets take that a client is being responsed at this moment. How can another client make a petition and been answered while the main thread is busy with the first client?

Comment: This is a matter of design. Asynchronous means that your call is not blocked until completion of the operation, thus if IOs are longer than logical code, you can simply use async IOs to accelerate the whole. But doing so doesn't means concurrency as with threads. With async there is concurrency in between IOs and logical code, while with threads you have a full concurrency even between logical code. Roughly. With async you can have the "system" writing an answer while reading a request, accepting a connection or computing something, a light form of concurrency.

Comment: A multi-threaded server doesn't have to use async IO, it usually makes little sense to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of the word "concurrent" is ambiguous.

You are right, an asynchronous server is not concurrent at all. It can process only one request at a time. But the key insight is that what most servers do is actually they take a request, do some light processing (parsing, serialization, validation, some light business logic, etc.) and then call external resources (e.g. some database). The server can then process other requests while waiting for the external resource. So it's only an illusion of being concurrent (processing happens one after another but really fast). And it works as long as the processing is relatively fast compared to io.

If your server is supposed to do some hard cpu computations then obviously there will be no concurrency at all. In that case the only way to make it concurrent is to add threads or processes (possibly on multiple machines).

Comment: `there will be no concurrency at all` - actually, it makes sense it will be. you'll just open up small number of threads, usually as the number of logical cores on you machine.

Comment: So, you mean that an async server always perform async operations, but if the server is busy because an operation's callback is being executed (for instance, a heavy IO operation), no other operation will be able to be performed, right?

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous IO does not make the server concurrent.

In fact, Asynchronous IO does not mean "multi-threaded" or "multi-processed" at all. Node.js servers are mono-threaded and using asynchronous IO.

Asynchronous IO just means your thread does not wait for the IO to finish, but does other stuff meanwhile (like accepting and processing new incoming requests).

So no, the premise that Asynchronous IO makes the server concurrent is wrong. it does not make it concurrent, it makes it **scalable**, as thread-per-request is not so scalable, but a proper thread-pool + event queue/coroutines are. the threads only deal with CPU bound tasks and the event queue/coroutines manages enqueuing and dequeuing started/finished IO operations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're only looking for a theoretical answer or a design example, but have you seen the [HTTP Server 3](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.http_server_3) example for boost.asio?

Concurrency is achieved by having a small thread pool to execute the work. When callbacks need to be handled, all threads calling `io_service.run()` can be chosen to execute the task.